# Why does this C not allow combining -- operator and & operator in this syntax

Tags: c, pointers

I'm trying to do something fairly simple. Of course it could be done with an extra line of code, but technically speaking, why does this not work?

> ```
> int foo = 5;
> int *bar = &(--foo);
> ```

GCC compiler tells me `"invalid lvalue in unary &"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `--foo` is not an lvalue (so named since they typicaly appeared on the left of an asignment).

It's the same problem with:

```
--foo = 7;
```

If, for some bizarre reason, you need it on one line, just use:

```
--foo; int *bar = &foo;
```

If you think you need it in one *instruction,* think again. Even if you make such a horrible monstrosity <sup>(a)</sup>, it will probably compile down to the same machine language sequence as that code snippet above.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> `int *bar = (--foo, &(foo));`

Comment: Could also do: `int *bar = --foo, &foo;`.

Comment: Close, @GMan, problematic since I think the comma is being taken as a declaration separator rather than the comma operator, but you can get around that by enclosing the whole lot within parentheses. Still, if someone bought that code to me for review, I'd have quite a lot of fun that day :-)

Comment: The reason I was trying to it was because I wanted to say function(&(--foo)) because I wanted to pass the value of (foo-1) by reference to the function. Of course, its horrible code, but I really wondering from a theory point.

Answer (score 2):

Technically speaking, it doesn't work because `--foo` is not an lvalue, but the unary `&` operator requires one.

From the C draft standard, section 6.5.16:

> An assignment expression has the value of the left operand after the assignment, but is not an lvalue.

While that doesn't directly cover the prefix decrement operator, section 6.5.3.1 makes it apply:

> The expression `++E` is equivalent to `(E+=1)`.

and

> The prefix `--` operator is analogous to the prefix `++` operator, except that the value of the operand is decremented.

And, of course, section 6.5.3.2:

> The operand of the unary `&` operator shall be either a function designator, the result of a `[]` or unary `*` operator, or an lvalue that designates an object that is not a bit-field and is not declared with the `register` storage-class specifier.

Answer (score 1):

Because `--foo` returns some temporal value, but `&` needs a variable to create a reference to it. So, you need do it in two steps:

```
int *bar = &foo;
--foo;
```

Answer (score 0):

because (--foo) is rvalue. like a number constant

Answer (score 0):

I have no clue why you might need to do this; but if the pointers should be equal.  If you do it in a statement ( comma delimited) then the last element in the statement is what is returned.  The following compiles and both variables are equal according to GCC.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
        int foo = 5;
        int *bar;
        printf("%p\n", &foo);
        bar = (int *)(--foo, &foo);
        printf("%p\n", bar);
        return -1;
}
```